# x86 4 byte aligning strings

Tags: x86, shellcode

I am learning about shellcodes and according to what I've read, before pushing strings onto the stack, we need to ensure that they are 4-byte aligned. Suppose I wanted to push the string `"open"` onto the stack. To do this we convert it into hex which results in:

```
\x6f\x70\x65\x6e
```

We then prepend the opcode for pushing ie. \x68 resulting in the string:

```
\x68\x6f\x70\x65\x6e
```

However, this hasnt been null terminated terminated. To do this I've seen 2 approaches in examples:

1. Using `\x68\x20\x20\x00`
2. Another using `\x6A\x00`

My question is whats the difference between the 2 approaches and how do I decide between them?

Comment: You probably meant `\x68\x20\x20\x20\x00` as the opcode `68` takes an *imm32* in 32/64 bit mode. The first one pushes a generic 32-bit value, which you set to three spaces followed by a null term. The second instruction pushes a sign-extended 8-bit value which you set to zero (thus it pushes 4 bytes of value 0).       
Usually the latter is better, it's shorter and doesn't introduces extra characters at the end of the string (which is not always allowed). But beware that null bytes are usually not allowed in shellcode's payload. Another trick is to make a zero in a register and push that.

Comment: `push 'n'` / `push 'xope'` would get the data on the stack (if this is 32-bit mode), with an extra character of garbage at the start, avoiding any zero bytes in the machine code as @MargaretBloom pointed out.  `lea ecx, [esp+1]` gives you a pointer to the `"open\0"` part.  If this is 64-bit code, it's even easier: `push imm32` sign-extends to 64-bit, so `push 'open'` just works.  But in the general case, yeah construct values in registers, e.g. with `mov reg, imm32` and a shift, then push.